# The new Meta Stack Overflow has the same skin as the old Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mso-mse-split, design

Say somebody was really busy at work and completely missed the network happenings of this week. He went offline before the system message went up and came back after the system message finally goes down.

Reputation aside, nothing will have *visibly* changed on the site, but this site is *completely different* from what it used to be.

I think the main thing that can be done is changed the MSO logo; perhaps the "meta" bit could go below the logo? A callout on the MSO ask question page would also work. Finally, at least for the first while, a dedicated OT close reason ("this is not relevant to Stack Overflow") wouldn't suck.

Comment: I understood MSO was going to get a MSE migration path... but apparently they're all sleeping or something so can't do it *shakes head*.

Comment: @shog9, status-bydesign that someone might not realize anything happened if they miss the week of jubilation? eek! it would be nice if there were *some* permanent change to signify turning over this new leaf. (maybe this should be feature-request instead then?)

Comment: I'm in no particular hurry to take down that banner.

Comment: i like the way you think @shog. i'll keep crossing my fingers for a new logo some time before the banner eventually does come down :)

Comment: So... what happened to the reputation/badges we had gathered in the past? Are they gone for good?

Answer (score 10):

You raise a good point that someone could completely miss the transition. Short of keeping that obnoxious banner up... forever, I think a re-imagining of the existing concept wouldn't be a bad idea.

Looking at other meta sites, the approach is generally a desaturated main, with "Meta" somewhere on the logo, in a color matching main. Stack Overflow's is no exception to this, but other sites have certainly seen more refinement in the interim years. For starters, the offset, stenciled pattern of the existing logo could be cleaned up, and the color matched to Stack Overflow's main color.

[image]

Other incremental improvements would stem naturally from a new logo.